# unable to upgrade R on aws instance of ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I'm trying up grade R (currently 3.1.3) to the latest using

```
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
```

and get the message that  I'm already on the latest:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
r-base-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
```

Here is my current version

```
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09) -- "Smooth Sidewalk"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

So I am clearly not on the latest version.

Comment: Have you tried running `apt-get update` in advance?

Comment: Yep. I ran that first.

Comment: A telling command (in addition to @Daniel's comment) is `apt-cache show r-base-dev`; if done immediately after `apt-get update`, it tells a lot. But ...

Comment: The "currency" of an application in a distribution depends on many factors, including the distro itself (ubuntu, debian), what "beta-level" you are accepting, optional PPAs, etc. For instance, in the [Ubuntu Vivid universe package list](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid/universe/binary-i386/Packages.gz), the most recent version is `r-base_3.1.2-2`. Newer PPAs are likely offering 3.2.2, but you have to intentionally configure them. Perhaps not as "clearly" straight-forward as you had hoped.